# How to make make counter run after everything is visible?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a small countdown with Javascript only. So no jQuery or stuff. Tried several things and searched a lot, but now I got a problem I can't solve.

My idea is to make a counter run down, while the user gets the opportunity to select an item. When he doesn't do it before the counter is 0, the computer get a point.
Only problem; the script don't make the hidden items visible. Only the start button is holded down and in the console are the logs of the timer visible.
Any solution how I can make the timer run between everything is loaded and the user chose / did run out of time?

```
function countdown() {
    for (startklaar === "ja"; timer >= 0; timer--) {
        var timersec = Math.floor(timer / 1000);
        console.log("Timer: " + timer);
        console.log("Timersec: " + timersec);
        document.getElementById('timerzin').textContent = ("Nog " + timersec + " seconden!");
    }
    if (timer === 0) {
        document.getElementById('timerzin').textContent = ("Tijd is op!");
        scoreComp++;
        statusronde = "stop";
        ronde(statusronde);
        }
}

function ronde() {
    if (statusronde === "start") {
        document.getElementById("steenme").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("papierme").hidden = false; 
        document.getElementById("schaarme").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("startronde").hidden = true;
//      timedown = setInterval(countdown(), 10000);
        countdown();
        startklaar = "ja";
    }
    else if (statusronde === "stop") {
        clearInterval(timedown);
//      document.getElementById("steenme").hidden = true;
//      document.getElementById("papierme").hidden = true;  
//      document.getElementById("schaarme").hidden = true;
        document.getElementById("startronde").hidden = false;
        startklaar = "nee";
    }
    else { console.log("Rare status: " + statusronde); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One big problem is that you need to change to style part of the element to change its visibility, I'm not sure if `.hidden` will work.

I also fixed some likely bugs:

```
var scoreComp = 0;
var statusronde;
var startklaar;
function countdown() {
    var timer;
    for (timer = 0; timer >= 0 && startklaar === "ja"; timer--) {
        var timersec = Math.floor(timer / 1000);
        console.log("Timer: " + timer);
        console.log("Timersec: " + timersec);
        document.getElementById('timerzin').innerHTML = ("Nog " + timersec 
        + " seconden!");
    }
    if (timer === 0) {
        document.getElementById('timerzin').innerHTML = ("Tijd is op!");
        scoreComp++;
        statusronde = "stop";
        ronde(statusronde);
    }
}

function ronde(status) {
    if (status === "start") {
        document.getElementById("steenme").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("papierme").style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById("schaarme").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startronde").style.display = "block";
//      timedown = setInterval(countdown, 10000);
        countdown();
        startklaar = "ja";
    }
    else if (status === "stop") {
        clearInterval(timedown);
//      document.getElementById("steenme").style.display = "block";
//      document.getElementById("papierme").style.display = "block";  
//      document.getElementById("schaarme").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("startronde").style.display = "none";
        startklaar = "nee";
    }
    else { console.log("Rare status: " + status); }
}
```

Comment: Also - you commented out some things that would have been required for the program to work correctly, are you aware that `//` in a line denotes a comment (ignored text)?